# Insert query becomes executed two times instad of one

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have trouble while trying to insert data into a mysql database with InnoDB tables. The problem is the following: When `gamescreen.php` gets executed anyhow becomes after the first inserted row another one inserted with another random picked row from `questions_de` where `$id` is `0` where the first have `5`. Why becomes another one created?

table questions_de:

> id int
>
> question varchar
>
> answer_m float

```
    $.ajax({ url: 'gamescreen.php',
 data: {id: '5'},
 type: 'GET',
 cache: false,
 async: false,
 success: function() {
        window.location.href='gamescreen.php';      
          }
});
```

**gamescreen.php**

```
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
}
    $new = 0;
         try {
                                $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=max_com_db_socgame",$user,$password);

                                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                                 $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM user WHERE id = '$id'
        LIMIT 1"; // 
          if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
              // then after fetchColumn
             $user2name = $res->fetchAll();

           }

           if($user2name > 0) {
               //do something
           }
           else {

               echo "Sorry something happen wrong with our servers.";
           }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {


        }

        try {
                                $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=max_com_db_socgame",$user,$password);

                                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                                 $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM questions_de
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1"; // 
          if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
              // then after fetchColumn
             $question = $res->fetchAll();

           }

           if($question > 0) {
               //do something
           }
           else {

               echo "Sorry something happen wrong with our servers.";
           }
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {


        }


                        try {
                                $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=max_com_db_socgame",$user,$password);

                                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                                $sql = "INSERT INTO game_create (user1, user2, user1name, user2name, question, questionid, answer)
                                VALUES ('".$_COOKIE["userid"]."', '".$id."', '".$_COOKIE["username"]."', '".$user2name[0]["username"]."', '".$question[0]['question']."', '".$question[0]['id']."', '".$question[0]['answer_m']."')";

                                if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
                                        //echo "New Record Inserted Successfully";
                                }
                                else{
                                       // echo "Data not successfully Inserted.";
                                }
                                $new = $dbh->lastInsertId();
                                $dbh = null;
                        }
                        catch(PDOException $e)
                        {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                        }

                        if ($new > 0) {

                        } else {
                        echo 'Sorry something went wrong.';    
                        }
```

Comment: May be second time due to this `window.location.href='gamescreen.php';  `

Comment: Have you checked if your javascript is executed twice maybe?

Comment: @Saty Why is this the mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: close `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {` at the end of your page!! OR after success redirect to some other  successful page or just show alert message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue looks like its with this line:

success: function() {window.location.href='gamescreen.php';}

When your AJAX runs successfully its redirecting to gamescreen.php which in turn triggers the PHP code over again giving you two runs of the code

either simply remove the AJAX and link directly to gamescreen.php if thats the page you want to end up on or instead create a new page to redirect users to on success - eg success.php

Comment: Oh man thank you I've tried to solve it 36h :D. I made it now with a link button.